# Why does "WordPress" not show up in the 2022 Developer Survey?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-developer-survey

WordPress does not show as an option in the section "Web frameworks and technologies" of the 2022 Developer Survey:

https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=announcement-banner&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2022&utm_content=results#section-most-popular-technologies-web-frameworks-and-technologies

Some competitors, such as [Drupal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal) and [Laravel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel), do. In the 2019 survey, WordPress was "loved" by 40% of the respondents, while Drupal, that makes the cut for 2022 survey, is only loved by 2.2%.

Can we re-add WordPress to that list, considering that it is widely more popular?

It did show up in 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017:

- https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-platforms
- https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#technology-_-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-platforms
- https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#technology-_-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-platforms
- https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#technology-_-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-platforms

Comment: cross-site dupe / related (MSO): [Add CMS popularity to Stack Overflow Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418575/add-cms-popularity-to-stack-overflow-developer-survey)

Comment: Also: there was a call to comment on proposed options before the survey went live: [Review our technical responses for the 2022 Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417201/review-our-technical-responses-for-the-2022-developer-survey)

Comment: Thank you for that link. I wasn't aware. Could we add WordPress as an option for the 2023 draft?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering this question:

> Why isn't WordPress in that list, considering that it is widely more popular?

No one mentioned WordPress when there was a callout by SE staff for review on the language / platform and/or technical responses Meta posts prior to finalizing the survey:

- [Review our languages and platforms for Dev Survey 2021](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407253/review-our-languages-and-platforms-for-dev-survey-2021)
- [Review our technical responses for the 2022 Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417201/review-our-technical-responses-for-the-2022-developer-survey)

WordPress is popular and has a dedicated following. Unfortunately, they don't seem to visit Meta often enough to be vocal when it matters most. Maybe next year. You might want to subscribe to the [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) tag over on Meta Stack Overflow so you don't miss next years post.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for clarifying. I have edited my question slightly to tone down the "complaint" tone a bit. I'll subscribe to that tag, but if anyone beats me to it next year to include it, I appreciate it.